# Numpy and Pandas interpolation also changes the original data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate data for some missing days. The orginal data is;

```
2012-06-27 00:00:00 17
2012-06-27 01:00:00 17
2012-06-27 02:00:00 18
2012-06-27 03:00:00 18
2012-06-27 04:00:00 19
2012-06-27 05:00:00 20
2012-06-27 06:00:00 22
2012-06-27 07:00:00 23
2012-06-27 08:00:00 25
2012-06-27 09:00:00 27
2012-06-27 10:00:00 27
2012-06-27 11:00:00 29
2012-06-27 12:00:00 29
2012-06-27 13:00:00 30
2012-06-27 14:00:00 30
2012-06-27 15:00:00 29
2012-06-27 16:00:00 28
2012-06-27 17:00:00 26
2012-06-27 18:00:00 25
2012-06-27 19:00:00 24
2012-06-27 20:00:00 23
2012-06-27 21:00:00 23
2012-06-27 22:00:00 16
2012-06-27 23:00:00 15
2012-06-29 00:00:00 15
2012-06-29 01:00:00 16
2012-06-29 02:00:00 16
2012-06-29 03:00:00 16
2012-06-29 04:00:00 17
2012-06-29 05:00:00 17
2012-06-29 06:00:00 18
2012-06-29 07:00:00 19
2012-06-29 08:00:00 20
2012-06-29 09:00:00 22
2012-06-29 10:00:00 22
2012-06-29 11:00:00 22
2012-06-29 12:00:00 22
2012-06-29 13:00:00 22
2012-06-29 14:00:00 22
2012-06-29 15:00:00 22
2012-06-29 16:00:00 21
2012-06-29 17:00:00 19
2012-06-29 18:00:00 17
2012-06-29 19:00:00 16
2012-06-29 20:00:00 15
2012-06-29 21:00:00 14
2012-06-29 22:00:00 14
2012-06-29 23:00:00 13
```

As you can see 2014-12-28 is missing, so I tried to interpolate it using both Numpy and Pandas. 
For Numpy the code is;

```
def inter_lin_nan(ts_temp, rule):
ts_temp = ts_temp.resample(rule)
mask = np.isnan(ts_temp)
# interpolling missing values
ts_temp[mask] = np.interp(np.flatnonzero(mask), np.flatnonzero(~mask),ts_temp[~mask])
return(ts_temp)
```

and with Pandas I used;

```
df_temp=df_temp.asfreq('1h')
df_temp['Temp2'] = df_temp['temp'].interpolate(method='linear')
```

The problem is, both of these method does interpolate for the missing day, but they also change original data for 2014-12-29. Do you know why this is happening or am I missing something?

Comment: `2014-12-28` is outside of the presented data set. Could you post the relevant data?

Comment: There's not enough information here.

Comment: Also... `2014-12-14 22:00:00 -1` is followed by `2014-12-14 23:00:00 8`?

Comment: @N.Wouda It is the relevant data, `2014-12-28` is missing in the data, that's why I am doing interpolation. @Erip: these are temperature readings and also what else you need as information?

Comment: @muhammadwaseem [wiki on interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation): "interpolation is a method of constructing new data points **within** the range of a discrete set of known data points." You do not present use with the full range, so how do you expect us to be able to replicate your problem?

Comment: @N.Wouda: I am new to StackOverflow but can provide you with the full data. I am unable to attach file, any suggestions?

Comment: @muhammadwaseem just post the days surrounding `2014-12-28`, that should be enough! So, say, the range `2014-12-27 0:00` to `2014-12-29 23:00`. That should be forty-something values.

Comment: @N.Wouda: I have added the data between `2014-12-27 0:00` and `2014-12-29 23:00`. Please have a look.

Comment: @muhammadwaseem are you sure? That's `2012-06-27` to `2012-06-29`, not `2014-12-27` to `2012-06-29`, is this correct? I am a bit confused.

Comment: @N.Wouda: Sorry, it is `2014-06-27 0:00` to `2014-06-29 23:00`. My apologies.

Comment: @muhammadwaseem `2012` or `2014`?

Comment: Sorry again, 2012. It's a typo. Will this make any difference on results? My apologies.

Comment: What you're looking for is extrapolation not interpolation since `2014-12-28` is beyond the observation range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem, but this works for me (assuming your data frame is indexed on datetime):

```
df_resampled = df.resample('1H').interpolate(method='linear')
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the lines overlap perfectly for the days where there is data: no original data is 'changed'. The interpolation seems to make sense too, and in this plot the missing values in the original series were set to 0 to allow a comparison.

Comment: Thanks for this, I will give it a try and will update here.

Comment: `2014-12-28` is beyond the observation range. You can't use interpolation.